# How to get another text-file be opened in new tab in mousepad?

Tags: xubuntu, gedit, mousepad

Earlier when I used to gedit in Unity environment, when I opens a text file with gedit (considering one file is already opened in gedit), then it opens in new tab in already opened window.

After installing `xubuntu-desktop`, Now I am using **`mousepad`** (default text-editor in Xubuntu) in Xubuntu. But when I opens text-file (considering one is already opened window) it opens in separate window instead of in new tab in opened window.

Thus, **How do I get another text-file opened in new-tab instead of separate window?**

Note: If I open files using File>Open in mousepad or selecting multiple files and openwith mousepad then it opens in multiple tabs but this is different case.

---

To understand difference quickly try following commands and see difference:

1. `gedit & gedit` :- gedit opens with two tabs
2. `mousepad & mousepad` :- mousepad opens with two separate windows

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it isn't possible: https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11196 and https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=9129

It should be said that using gedit in Xubuntu is not an issue.  Both use gtk, which makes gedit a native application to Xubuntu, in a sense.

So forget about trying to get mousepad to work like gedit.  Just keep using gedit!

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but for the benefit of anyone looking now, this is possible (at least as of version 0.5.4 of Mousepad). There's now an option in the preferences to open files in new tabs under Preferences > Window > Notebook tabs

[image: See this screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

How ever Mousepad doesn't behaves like gedit and it opens new file in new window; you can use menu option : **File -> Open** option from Mousepad.

Alternatively you can **drag** a text file to the already open Mousepad window to open the dragged file in a **new tab!**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I already mentioned about file>open in question (see note) but i will try your dragging idea.

Comment: Ahh, my bad, I missed that note.  Dragging file should work for sure, though.

Comment: yes, dragging is helpful.

Comment: Glad it helped.  Please accept the answer to mark the question as solved.  Might help someone else too.

Comment: This is alternative solution ; not expected from question. I will revise and upvote your ans. when i am on pc (tomorrow)